# How to launch Appium test with a certain language keyboard on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, keyboard, automated-tests, appium

I am running tests which require having different keyboards open while typing throughout the app. I want to be able to run a test that perhaps launches a script that changes the default language before the test begins. I know you can run scripts which do similar things to change the state of the simulator however I cannot find where the keyboard settings are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time trying to figure this one out.

**Here's what I've got for you:**

- To use different keyboards, you need to tell manually the Simulator which languages you plan on using when you type.
- From then on, whenever the keyboard is up, there will be a `UIAKey` named `Next Keyboard` that looks like a Globe.
- Do a long press on it to get an action sheet open with all the different languages, or click it once to cycle through the keyboards.

**Step-by-step:**

1. Go into `System Preferences` on the simulator
2. Click on `General`
3. Click on `Keyboard`
4. Click on `Keyboards`
5. Click on `Add New Keyboard...`
6. Select `(Language)`
7. Close the Simulator
8. Open your app
9. Click on a `Textfield`
10. See the `Globe Button`
11. Click the `Globe Button`
12. Keyboard should now be in `(Language)`

Comment: My answer isn't the best way to go... You should modify the simulator's plist file before launching it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31442185/3622606