# How to launch iOS Simulator in specific language from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcodebuild

I need to lauch iOS Simulator that uses specific language using command line. So I found that I can use

```
instruments -w <device>
```

and it is working great, I can set specific device. But how can I run simulator with specific language? I've tried adding

```
-AppleLanguages -AppleLocale
```

but there are some warnings:

```
Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid: -AppleLanguage
```

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to launch `iOS Simulator` with specific language is to change contents of its `.GlobalPreferences.plist` file. Using `xcrun` tool will not work because it passess arguments to launched app and not changing language of simulator itself. Manipulation on `.GlobalPreferences.plist` is quite difficult because it is a binary `plist` file, so you cannot modify it as 'normal' `xml`. The easiest way to change its contents is to write simple `Xcode Command Line Tool application`, Foundation `SDK` has all tools needed to modify binary `plists`.

Comment: Just in addition to make someone's pain less hurt, the plist is located at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/${YOURID}/data/Library/Preferences` since Xcode 8 I believe... (Changed path from previous Xcode versions) Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you can edit the plist file right now and leave the language key for your desired and delete the others and it will work. Also I believe you can just edit it for once with classic plist editor and you are okay...

Comment: This is a script I use to change locale in simulator before launching:
https://gist.github.com/rumax/2470ec2fcc3ef84420542f049589407e
See related article:
https://itnext.io/you-dont-need-gui-or-how-to-control-ios-simulator-from-command-line-bf5cfa60aed2

Comment: @mmccabe any hint on why Simulator version 12.4 always changes the default keyboard settings even after setting it in `GlobalPreferences.plist`?

Comment: I ended up with a doing two things to end up with only one keyboard layout in the iOS Simulator. First as described in this answer I updated the GlobalPreferences.plist for that particular Simulator. Then I started the Simulator and before my actual UI Test I automated the Settings app of iOS to remove the keyboard which is automatically added by iOS Simulator once I start it. This way I ended up with only the keyboard layout I want to have. To get the simulator ID: https://itnext.io/you-dont-need-gui-or-how-to-control-ios-simulator-from-command-line-bf5cfa60aed2

Answer (score 6):

To run your app must be installed and located (if not, will open default language)

Use this command to run your app with some language

```
xcrun simctl launch <deviceid> <appid> -AppleLanguages "(pt-BR)"
```

Sample:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -arch i386 install DSTROOT=SomeFolder
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator)"
xcrun simctl install booted SomeFolder/Applications/YourApp.app
xcrun simctl launch booted com.yourdomain.yourapp -AppleLanguages "(pt-BR)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export UDID=202B1006-C2DE-4CC6–8791–6EA4C3782XXX
plutil -replace AppleLocale -string "en_GB" ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$UDID/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
xcrun simctl shutdown $UDID
xcrun simctl boot $UDID
```