# How to change the language/locale on ios device through terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal

Is it possible to change the locale on ios device through terminal like on android using adb commands?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428132/how-to-launch-ios-simulator-in-specific-language-from-command-line